# Bash environment variable not inherited by node process

Tags: node.js, bash

Inlining the env works `SOMETHING=hello node -e "console.log(process.env.SOMETHING)"`, but I want `node` to read the environment variables from the spawning shell.

The following code will print `hello` (note that echo can read the environment)

```sh
SOMETHING=hello
echo $SOMETHING
```

However the following code prints `undefined`:

```sh
SOMETHING=hello
node -e "console.log(process.env.SOMETHING)"
```

Why can't node read the shell environment? Can I make it read that somehow?

Comment: You have set a **shell** variable `SOMETHING`, but not an **environment** variable. By default, shell variables don't go into the environment.

Comment: I remeoved the node.js tag, because the question is not really related to Node.js. You would run into the same problem if you would just use a bash subshell: `FOO=x; bash -c 'echo ${FOO:-undefined}'` prints _undefined_.

Comment: In `echo $SOMETHING`, the `echo` command is not getting the value of `SOMETHING` from the environment, the shell is expanding the variable and then passing the result to `echo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run like this:

```
export SOMETHING=hello
node -e "console.log(process.env.SOMETHING)"
```

OR

```
SOMETHING=test node -e "console.log(process.env.SOMETHING)"
```

Comment: 2nd example is fixed now by @Moshe